# Server response from json to javascript alert

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am using webrtc(javascript,json,ajax) client to send request and c#web service to validate on server. I am posting a json request and the result is being displayed as xml in the console of the browser. Is there a way to get the response as an alert or pop up message using javvascript?

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: urlPath,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
        data: jsond,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Details saved successfully!!!" + response);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        },
```

Comment: What is the output when you give alert(xhr.responseText);, I mean a sample of output will help here.

Comment: If you're requesting JSON and getting XML, it may be that's all the service supports responding with. The server application has to support JSONP for that option to work properly.

Comment: Also, what is the scope of xhr in alert(xhr.responseText);. I mean you need to have xhr in the success function scope to extract the information i.e. responseText

Answer (score 1):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ the success: of ajax call is being passed three parameters
1. Data(plainObject)
2. TextStatus(string)
3.  jqXHR object(typeof jqXHR)

To extract the serverResponse, write this in the "success" Callback

```
success: function (data,TextStatus, xhr) {

            alert(xhr.responseText);
        },
```

Or if you want to display the data(as returned from the server), then you need to parse your data like this.

```
success: function (data,TextStatus, xhr) {
                var newData = JSON.parse(data)
                alert(newData);
            }
```